# Gallileo HAS - Android support

Tags: gps, software-recommendations, android

Galileo started to provide corrections (HAS) at the beginning of the year. They are distributed either directly on the E6-B frequency or over the Internet via the Ntrip protocol. According to EUSPA, it should be possible to use internet corrections to refine measurements on a smartphone, but the corrections must be supported by the app.

I need to measure points in the field and more accuracy would be beneficial.

Are there any Android apps that implement HAS corrections?

Comment: I believe its down to the gps chipset in the Android device.  https://www.gsc-europa.eu/support-to-developers/galileo-compatible-devices  device/chip list https://www.usegalileo.eu/EN/inner.html#data=smartphone

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.